# Dúvida Laravel + Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Eu possuo a seguinte tabela abaixo, com uma listagem, existe uma TD, a qual o usuário pode escolher entre sim e não, tag option do html, gostaria de saber como fazer a mudança de sim para não ou vice-versa, via ajax, para que não seja necessário ficar fazendo requisição cliente servidor, e atualizar via ajax. Abaixo segue imagem de como é a tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando atualmente fazer o ajax da seguinte maneira, mas está dando erro:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#viewpergunta').change(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
   jQuery.ajax({
      url: '../perguntascadastro/1',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
         viewpergunta: jQuery('#viewpergunta').serialize(),
      },
      success: function(result){
         console.log(result);
      }});
   });
});
```

Abaixo segue minha rota a qual da para atualizar no banco, a mesma rota que uso para cadastro, serve para atulizar.

```
Route::any('/perguntascadastro/{id}', 'PerguntasController@addPerg')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Meu controller

```
public function addPerg(PerguntasRequest $request, $id){

    if($id == 0){
        Perguntas::create($request->all());
    }else{
        Perguntas::find($request->id)->update(Request::except($id));
    }

    return redirect()->action('PerguntasController@index', $id = 0);
}
```

Meu Html apenas a parte da table

```
<td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="viewpergunta" name="viewpergunta">
                        <option value="{{ $lista->viewpergunta == 1 ? 1 : 0 }}">{{ $lista->viewpergunta == 1 ? "Sim" : "Não" }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ $lista->viewpergunta == 1 ? 0 : 1 }}">{{ $lista->viewpergunta == 1 ? "Não" : "Sim" }}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Comment: que erro está dando?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)

Comment: Como está setado no cabeçalho  o seu meta?

Comment: Como to usando o laravel, estou utilizando só "@csrf"

 `<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />`

Comment: Tenta adicionar mais um assim `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: agora deu erro  422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88919/discussion-between-adventistaam-and-daniel-rosendo-de-souza).

Comment: resolvido? ja tentou debugar sua função para ver se o ajax chega até la? vale ressaltar que para analisar o resultado você ira ter que olha a aba network no navegador!